# LDAP Directory Synchronization Tools

Tags: ldap, synchronization, identity

I'm in charge of renovating an old system that has to synchronize identities between multiple kinds of LDAP servers: Active Directory, OpenLDAP, ApacheDS.

I also need to do some attribute translation, and implement basic scripting in order to populate given attributes with semantic data (e.g. originating partner).

We used to do that with Maxware software, not sold anymore.
I have in Mind the Microsoft Forefront Identity Manager --> too heavy!
Also, Directory Wizards's "UnitySync" Tool might help --> far too basic...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Identity Management products on the market will have the ability to synchronize identities between different directory services and vendors.
ForgeRock OpenIDM is one of them.
Alternately, you might want to take a look at lsc-project.org, which is just an open source LDAP synchronization tool, however, I don't know how it works with more than 2 sources to synchronize.

Comment: Yes, I already found one: `Unitysync`, edited by "Directory Wizards". Quite simple and efficient, thus borderline too simple. Same tool including some schedduling would be perfect fit!

Comment: How about LSC? An open source project, I doesn't have more feedback about it.

Comment: LSC (lsc-project.org) does the work. It's used in production at several organizations, mostly to sync between one AD and one open source LDAP server. Beware, that synchronizing data is easy, making sure passwords are actually synchronized and consistent is way more complex, but properly dealt with by products like OpenIDM.